# MySql query to check row_1 of column_1 is in between the row_1 and row_2 of column2

Tags: mysql

In the below table, I want to check the following using mysql query.

Any *row_x* of c1 is in between the *row_x* and *row_x+1* of c2? So the result for the below table should be 2. Because 2 in c1 is in between 1 and 3 of c2

```
C1    || C2  || 
---------------
2     || 1   || 
5     || 3   || 
6     || 4   || 
7     || 5   ||
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use math in the `WHERE` clause so:

```
select * from table where c1 between c2 and (c2 + 1)
```

should work.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hE2oswGaEcJe9h8ZSdjURV/0